# Pyspark command not recognized (Ubuntu)

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have successfully installed pyspark using anaconda and configured paths in the `.bashrc` file.
Post typing `pyspark` command, it opens `Jupyter-notebook` in which `python` code is working properly. Like, `print "Hello"` etc.

But when I execute the Pyspark commands like `collect()`, `take(5)` etc, it gives an error that `"Cannot run program '/usr/bin/Python-3.7.4". Permission denied.`

It is referring wrong directory, as `Python-3.7.4` is installed in the `Anaconda` directory.

Is there any configuration/step, I need to perform to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` environment variables to the correct Python 3 distribution path

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Thanks for the help bro.

Comment: By changing the PYSPARK_PYTHON variable, previously it was referring /usr/bin/Python-3.7.4 file. Changed this variable to $HOME/anaconda3/bin/Python-3.7.4.